# Where should we define Go interface in multiple Consumer scenario ? What about interface in producer to show generality?

Tags: go, interface, dependencies, solid-principles, dependency-inversion

Can someone give me a concrete example to this advise ?

`https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#interfaces`

So is this how i follow it ?

```
package worker

type interface DB {
  getAllTable()
}


type worker struct {
  db DB
}

func (w worker) doSomething() {
  w.db.getAllTable() 
}
```

---

```
package listener

type interface DB {
  getAllTable()
}

type listener struct {
  db DB
}

func (l listener) doSomething() {
  l.db.getAllTable() 
}
```

---

```
package msql

type mysql struct {}

func (mysql) getAllTable() {
}
```

Is it alright to duplicate the interfaces in 2 places to satisfy ‘define consumer where it is consumed’.

---

What about using interface to show generality ? It’s defining interface not where it is consumed

For example hash/crc32 and hash/adler32 implementing hash.Hash32

Comment: It's fine to duplicate it, but the given code doesn't need to have either copy because it's never referenced. Define an interface where it is consumed.

Comment: Is there a concrete example of this on standard library / large scale project ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be difficult to maintain? Like even renaming a method will be N times vs 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the `DB` interface in to a different package, then the `worker` and `listener` packages could both use it.